# Keep sub running after form is closed

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a sub called notify in a class called "sys". I'm using this sub as a notification form as a replacement for notifyicon/balloontip.

So it looks something like this...

```
sys.notify("message")
```

My issue is that I need to be able to show the notification and have the form close shortly after. The way I have it right now, the form closes while the notification is still active, and the notification gets cut off.

Is there any way to keep it going even after the form that called it is closed, or do I have to wait until the notification is done before I can close the form?

Comment: Which UI framework?  WinForm, WPF, ASP, etc...

Comment: Could you provide a bit more detail?  Does `sys` inherit from `Form`?  Could you show some more code and give some more detail about what you are trying to do?  Could you show the code for `notify`?

Comment: It's winform. Sys is just a class filled with subs that don't belong anywhere else. Just for organization. Nothing technical. notify is based off of this... http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?351757-Animated-Window-Effects-with-quot-Toast-quot-popup-demo&p=4154751&viewfull=1#post4154751

Comment: Hiding the form and closing it with a Timer would be a simple solution.

Comment: Does you application finish running when you close the form?

Answer (score 0):

there are possibilities.

1) the notify part: code it in a different thread, so it will not close even the main form is closed.

2) a simpler way: in main form closing event, check whether the notify part is shown or main form is invisible, if no, close the form. if yes, hide the form (invisible), and abort closing event. In the notify part, when closing notify itself, check whether main form is invisible, if yes, close it, then close notify.

The key in 2) is making main form invisble instead of closing.

Answer (score 0):

The key is starting a thread that is not a background. So that your form will be closed but the process will keep running until that non-background thread(s) is done thus keeping your ballontip visible.

To the place(sub or function) where you want to display baloontip put this:

```
Dim x As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf somesub)
x.IsBackground = False
x.Start()
```

And put this somewhere:

```
Private Sub somesub()
        sys.notify("message")
End Sub
```